# Goal URL missing randomly

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup a goal using regex. It is missing some target URLs randomly. I tried it on chrome, firefox, opera and safari; tried while user logged-in and without; tried incognito mode; tried with delay and without delay but results are same. If i perform some steps once, it gets miss, then try same steps again, it gets hit, then try same steps yet again, it gets miss again. The order could be any. Hit and miss URLs have no difference other than unique IDs. Point is goals are missing randomly. A colleague of mine said its how GA works but i cannot buy it.

Can anyone explain whats going on?

My regex is:

```
(.*)/cleaning\-maid\-services/(.*)confirmation(.*)booking=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outside a character class hyphens do not need to be escaped. Other than that there is not enough information. E.g. a goal is measured only once per session, this might look like some goals are missing (if they happen within the same session, so you'd need to delete the ga cookie every time you test). And it's hard to debug a regex if one does not know what the regex is supposed to match. Plus you should include a screenshot of your goal setup.

Comment: The session issue was in my mind so i tried incognito but nothing happened. Thanks for the regex tip, i will make that change. I do not think problem is with regex thou because in that case, it shouldn't be matching to any URL (as i mentioned, hit and miss URLs are same except IDs).